# How to check remote image exists in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image

Below is the code :

```
<div ng-repeat="u in users">
<!--I will always receive a URL -->
<div ng-if="u.imageUrl"> <!--Here I want to check if the provided URL is active-->
 <!--Only seen if image url is live and active -->
</div>
<div>
<!--do some other things-->
</div>
</div>
```

e.g. : `http://www.pacinno.eu/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/placeholder1.png` is active URL but `http://www.pacinno.eu/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/placeholder11.png` is not.
Also `users` may have many records as signin increases.

Comment: angular-img-fallback could this be something that you are looking?

Comment: If I'm correct angular-image-fallback is used to show alternate image.
But I straightforwardly don't  want to show that div.

Comment: <img ng-src may work in this scenario. Please check

Comment: I know about `ng-src`. But what if I want to hide my div ?

Comment: dont know if this would work but maybe fallback to 1x1 pixel image?

Comment: I'm not getting you.Please elaborate

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a directive:

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/zh415hk3/)

JS:

```
.directive('userAvatar', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var placeholder = 'path/to/your/placeholder.jpg';

            scope.$watch(function() {
                return attrs.ngSrc;
            }, function (value) {
                if (!value) {
                    element.attr('src', placeholder);  
                }
            });

            element.bind('error', function() {
                element.attr('src', placeholder);  
            });
        }
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="u in users">
    <div>
      <img ng-src="{{u.imageUrl}}" user-avatar />
    </div>
<div>
```

So now if the `ng-src` value is a 404 not found image it will be replaced with the default `placeholder`

Comment: Thanks but I know this already. I don't want any alternate image.
You can check my question that I'm want my `div` to be hidden if URL in `u.imageUrl` is not active or not found.